# The proof that a permutation and its conjugate have the same cycle structure from Cooper's notes

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I've been idly reading "Cooper's Notes" on graph theory the past few days.

[Following one example, he states](http://www.coopersnotes.net/docs/groups/CHAP02%20Permutations.pdf) (see $\S2.10$ Conjugates) that

> "the permutation and its conjugate have the same cycle structure."

where a conjugate of a permutation $a$ is defined as $b^{-1}ab$ for an arbitrary permutation $b$ on the same set.

How interesting! I think. It's followed by a theorem:

> **Theorem 2**: The conjugate of $a=(x_1\:x_2\:\dots\:x_n)\dots$ by $b$ is $c=a^b=(b(x_1)\:b(x_2)\dots\:b(x_n))\dots$

no problem yet. Then the proof begins:

> **Proof:** We'll show that $ab=bc$ from which it follows that $b^{-1}ab=c$.

Wait a minute. First of all, $c$ is *defined* as $b^{-1}ab$. Shouldn't it be the other way around? Show that $b^{-1}ab=c$ means $ab=bc$?

Second, and more importantly, all that this shows is that $ab$ has the same cycle structure as $bc$. Why should $ab=bc$ mean that $c$ has the same cycle structure as $a$?

The proof itself is short, which I reproduce here:

> Now $ab(x_1)=b(a(x_1))=b(x_2)$ and $bc(x_1)=c(b(x_1))=b(x_2)$ Thus
> $ab$ and $bc$ have the same effect on the symbol $x_1$. Similarly they
> have the same effect on any symbol in the cycle notation for $a$. If
> $z$ is any other symbol then it's fixed by $a$ so
> $ab(z)=b(a(z))=b(z)$. Since $z$ is not present in the cycle notation
> for $c$ it's fixed by $c$ and so $bc(z)=c(b(z))=b(z)$. We've thus
> shown that $ab$ and $bc$ behave identically on all symbols so $ab=bc$.

What am I missing? Why does this proof have anything at all to do with the Theorem? Note that while I'd be interested in seeing a different proof, I'm more interested in why this specific proof works.

Comment: Firstly, I believe the author means to define c as this final equation in theorem 2, and then shows that this is indeed the conjugate by proving that ab=bc.  For your second point, to see that theorem 2 proves the claim, consider the definition of cycle type (in particular the disjointness of the cycles in the presentation) and see if you can spot the result.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to get it. I thought he was _defining_ $c=a^b$, and above that (in the author's text, not in my post) the author defines $a^b=b^{-1}ab$. So I thought the author was defining $c=b^{-1}ab$ then hoping to show that it equals $(b(x_1)\dots)$. Instead it's the other way around. Now it makes much more sense.

Comment: In other words, you answered my question--is there any way to promote this to the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Let's call the **theorem**:

> "the permutation and its conjugate have the same cycle structure."

Now take a permutation $\sigma$ written as a product of disjoint cycles

$$\sigma = c_1 \dots c_l$$

The conjugate is

$$a \sigma a^{-1} = (a c_1 a^{-1}) \dots (a c_l a^{-1}) \tag{1}$$ which according to **theorem 2** is a product of same length cycles. That are disjoint because the conjugation is bijective. This proves the **theorem**.

Remember that conjugation is a group homomorphism: this is what equation $(1)$ states.

Comment: Thanks for this. As I stated above, I think my mistake was a simple misreading: I thought the author was _defining_ $c=b^{-1}ab$ then somehow using the obvious fact (given the definition of $c$) that $ab=bc$ to show that $c=(b(x_1)\:b(x_2)\:\dots)\dots$. Instead, the author is_defining_ $c=(b(x_1)\:b(x_2)\:\dots)\dots$ and showing that such a $c$ means $ab=bc$ and hence $c=b^{-1}ab$.

Answer (score 1):

This is admittedly not an answer to your question, but just another proof of the claim.

---

The cycle structure of a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ shows itself when we consider the action of $\langle \sigma \rangle$ as a group of permutations on the set $X:=\{1,\dots,n\}$. By the Orbit-Stabilizer Theroem, we get:

$$|O_\sigma(i)||\operatorname{Stab}_\sigma(i)|=o(\sigma), \space\forall i\in X \tag 1$$

where:

$$\operatorname{Stab}_\sigma(i):=\{\sigma^k\mid \sigma^k(i)=i\} \le \langle\sigma\rangle, \space\forall i\in X \tag 2$$

Now, given $\tau\in S_n$, it is $(\tau\sigma\tau^{-1})^k=\tau\sigma^k\tau^{-1}$ (induction on $k$), so we get:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\operatorname{Stab}_{\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}}(i)&=\{\tau\sigma^k\tau^{-1}\mid (\tau\sigma^k\tau^{-1})(i)=i\} \\
&=\{\tau\sigma^k\tau^{-1}\mid \tau(\sigma^k(\tau^{-1}(i)))=i\} \\
&=\{\tau\sigma^k\tau^{-1}\mid \sigma^k(\tau^{-1}(i))=\tau^{-1}(i)\} \\
&=\{\tau\sigma^k\tau^{-1}\mid \sigma^k \in \operatorname{Stab}_\sigma(\tau^{-1}(i))\} \\
&=\tau\operatorname{Stab}_\sigma(\tau^{-1}(i)) \tau^{-1}, \space\forall \tau\in S_n,\forall i\in X\\
\tag 3
\end{alignat}

whence:

$$|\operatorname{Stab}_{\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}}(i)|=|\operatorname{Stab}_\sigma(\tau^{-1}(i))|, \space\forall \tau\in S_n,\forall i\in X \tag 4$$

But since $\forall \tau\in S_n, o(\tau\sigma\tau^{-1})=o(\sigma)$, we get that $(4)$ implies (again by the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem):

> $$|O_\sigma(\tau^{-1}(i))|=|O_{\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}}(i)|, \space\forall \tau\in S_n, \forall i\in X
> \tag 5$$

Therefore, for every $\tau\in S_n$, the orbits induced by $\langle \tau\sigma\tau^{-1}\rangle$ and $\langle \sigma\rangle$ are pairwise of equal size. Moreover, if we denote by $\mathcal{O}$ the set of orbits, we have:

> \begin{alignat}{1}
> |\mathcal{O}_{\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}}| &= \frac{1}{o(\tau\sigma\tau^{-1})}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\operatorname{Stab}_{\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}}(i)| \\
> &=\frac{1}{o(\sigma)}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\operatorname{Stab}_\sigma(\tau^{-1}(i))| \\
> &=\frac{1}{o(\sigma)}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\operatorname{Stab}_\sigma(i)| \\
> &=|\mathcal{O}_\sigma| \\
> \tag 6
> \end{alignat}

So, given $\sigma\in S_n$, for every $\tau\in S_n$ the natural actions of $\langle\sigma\rangle$ and $\langle\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}\rangle$ on $X$ induce the same number of orbits of the same size in pairs, namely $\sigma$ and $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$ have the same cycle structure.